# Displaying content based on drop-down menu selection sitewide

Tags: plugins, cookies

Here's the scenario:

Client provides services to a wide geographical area but pricing changes based on area. I don't want to incorporate geolocation, but I do want to permit the visitor to select from a drop-down menu of available locations and then "set" that user's selection sitewide so that when they visit the services page, they will see pricing that correlates to their selected area. I assume there would be a set of tables and the selection dropdown would set the appropriate table to be visible, I'm just not sure how to go about implementation, generally speaking.

I know this has to be a common feature to implement. It'd also be nice if this selection was retaining if the user closed and then re-opened their browser.

Any straightforward way to do this? Or am I looking at some complex development?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a cookie for this. You can then retrieve the cookie's value on any page where you need it, or in the `header.php`.

There are several ways you can do this, you can set cookies either via php or JavaScript.

Here is a good example on [how to set a cookie with php in WordPress](https://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/setting-a-cookie-with-wordpress). For JavaScript, there are several options. There's a jQuery cookie plugin, I recommend to google around for the different options.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I'm going to look into what you've suggested and go from there. I appreciate it.